# Limit to the number of characters read on sys_read

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I was playing around with some assembly programming and wrote some code to read in 4096 bytes from stdin using the syscall `sys_read`. However, it reads only around a 120 bytes from stdin.

Why does this happen? Is there any system level setting that I can change in order to read more bytes in one go? Is there any other way I can get around this limitation and force the program or sys_read to read in more bytes?

Answer (score 1):

`stdin` may be line buffered, do you happen to have a line feed at that position?
In general, however, `read` is allowed to return less than what you ask for. The solution is to read in a loop until you got all the bytes needed.